# Facebook API How to get a list of unpublished posts

Tags: facebook, api, post, get

I'm having a little bit of trouble getting a lists of posts of a page on facebook...

I'm using the url to get the posts of the page

```
 string.Format("{0}/posts, pageid)
```

But I cant take the unpublished posts.. It only gets the published posts... Is there any permission I have to use... or some other parameter? I also tried like this

```
  string.Format("{0}/posts?is_published=false", pageid)
```

... Didn't work...

Can someone help me?

Comment: Why are you posting the same question again?

Comment: These comments are not helpful.. this info is not in the docs linked. And you did not link the duplicate :-/

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

> `<pageId>/promotable_posts?is_published=false&fields=<the fields that you want>`

at [Facebook Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/)

Promotable posts include unpublished posts as well as regular posts. To get only unpublished posts, set is_published to false.

Fields are just comma delimited field names ex: `fields=message,created_time,comments`

[Docs/source](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/page/feed)